# How to create One to One Relationship using EDMX and POCO entities (database first)

Tags: c#, edmx, ef-database-first

I have 2 entities:

```
public class User
{
     public int UserId{ get; set; } //Primary Key
     public string UserName{ get; set; }

     public virtual Protocol MyProtocol{ get; set; } //Navigation
}

public class Protocol
{
     public int ProtocolId{ get; set; } //Primary Key
     public string ProtocolNumber{ get; set; }
     public int UserId{ get; set; } //Unique Key

     public virtual User Owner{ get; set; } //Navigation
}
```

In EDMX relationship map, I setted:

> End1 Multiplicity 1(User). 
>   End2 Multiplicity 0..1(Protocol).

I can't even build project, build throws:

Error 113: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Protocol' in relationship 'FK_Protocol_User'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be *.

Is there a way to do this, or User must have a Collection of Protocol even when he'll never have more than one protocol?